# How to find out OU of user by CN in Active Directory using cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, active-directory

I'm trying to write a code that running CMD via c#.
I have to find out the OU's user by CN.
There is a command that give me back this information?

Thank you

Comment: There's no guarantee that the CN of a user object is unique throughout the domain. Did you mean DN?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do this by creating a separate process when there's an entire [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx) dedicated to interacting with Directory services.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NET USER](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865(v=ws.10).aspx) command. This command can modify and read some data about user from local computer or domain. 
Maybe this data will be enough for you.

Switch /domain - Performs the operation on the domain controller in the computer's primary domain.

But why you don't query domain form c#?

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) is some info about it.

Comment: I hope you agree to disagree that this doesn't answer the question, since your proposed solution doesn't query the AD.

Comment: @kayess It can query AD, use switch /domain

Answer (score 0):

```
  string strCmdText;
  string office;
  strCmdText = "/C dsquery user -name  ID_" + textBox1.Text + "| dsget user -office;
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```